# Jar file does not find its dependent jars during its execution

Tags: ant, jar, classpath

I am trying to build a jar file out of your project using Ant 1.9.6.
I am not getting any compilation errors while building a jar file, but while executing it, I am getting NoClassDefFoundError.
I have verified in generated manifest file, I could see the required dependent jars were added to the class path like Class-Path: lib/a.jar lib/b.jar lib/c.jar.
The lib folder is parallel to src folder, so it could not be a issue.
I am running the jar on Mac OS.
Please could let me know any idea on this.

Thanks in advance
Ram

Comment: Whether the `lib` directory is parallel to `src` is irrelevant; the real concern is whether the `lib` directory is parallel to the JAR you're executing.  For example, if you're executing `build/test.jar`, then you need `build/lib/a.jar`, etc.  (If you show a snippet of your Ant script that includes `<java>` and relevant variables, someone might be able to give more specific advice.)

Comment: I did that change. It is working fine. Thank you very much:)

Comment: Ok, I've converted that to an answer.  You can accept it by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the lib directory is parallel to src is irrelevant; the real concern is whether the lib directory is parallel to the JAR you're executing. For example, if you're executing build/test.jar, then you need build/lib/a.jar, etc.